# How can i put two items next to each other?

Tags: html, css

And this is the website http://www.onetechsearch.com/recipes/?search=&images=1&from=&to=&cat=all

I have a question, I have two elements, my log (which is in html) and an arrow with a php script, and I wanted to put them next to each other. The arrow only shows on media devices, but I can't figure out a way to put them next to each other.

```
Search.php

<style type="text/css">
.mylogo
{
    margin: auto;
    display: block; 
}
</style>

<div class="site-wrap">

<div id="left-sidebar">
<div id="as-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                     <script>
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                            jQuery('#as-button').on('click', function(event) {  
                                jQuery('#as-button').toggleClass('pressed');
                                jQuery('#advanced-search').toggle(0,'show');
                            });
                        });
                     </script>
<html>
<img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/98e95c17ab.png" width="50%"  title="OneTechSearch" class="mylogo" alt="OneTechSearch" />
</html>



    <div id="advanced-search">
       <form action="recipes" method="GET" id="searchF1">                
       <input id="sfield" type="text" name="search" placeholder="keywords" <?php if (!empty($searched_term)) {
      echo 'value="'.$searched_term.'"';} ?>>
<td>
 <div id="picture-side">
      <label for="picture">
            <input type="radio" name="images" value="1" id="picture" label class="radio-inline" 
            <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='1'){ echo 'Checked';} ?>>With Pictures</label></option> 
</div>
<div id="picture-side1">
    <label for="picture2">
            <input type="radio" name="images" value="0" id="picture2" 
            <?php if(isset($_GET["images"]) && $_GET["images"]=='0'){ echo 'checked';} ?>>Without Pictures</label></option> 
    </div>          
</td>
```

And this is part of the code regarding the arrow

Styles.css

```
#advanced-search #as-button {
color:#fff;
padding:0.75em;
float:right;
margin: auto;
cursor:pointer;
height:80px;
border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}

#advanced-search #as-button.pressed{
background:#333;
}
#advanced-search #as-button i{
padding:0 0.5em;
font-size:2em;
#advanced-search #as-button .fa-search-plus {
font-size:1.4em;
#advanced-search #as-button {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 60%;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#advanced-search #as-button i {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
#advanced-search #as-button.pressed { background:none;}
#advanced-search #as-button.pressed i{ background:#333;}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `php`.. it's css/html issue.

Comment: it lloks a scary HTML - code. `<html>...</html>` among div-s and inside a code and orphan `<td></td>` without `<table>`.